# How can I write a HttpRequest that includes my Windows Live ID?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to write a little tool that lets me send *http* requests and responses, as I learn more about network functions in the *.NET framework*.

However, when dealing with a page that requires *Windows Live ID* authentication, I can't figure out how to write a request that includes my authentication information so that I can retrieve the page's *HTML*. I just end up with *HTML* that includes the *username* and *password* entry for a *Windows Live ID*.

Can someone show me a sample of how to write a `HttpRequest` in *C#* that will let me authenticate with a site that uses a *Windows Live ID*?

Thanks,

-Craig

Comment: Maybe using a webbrowser component in a windows form application is easier than mocking it using HttpRequest. Using HttpRequest on a https or website with form posts can be really hard to get working.

Comment: @Barfieldmv: That's what I ended up doing, using the WPF Browser control to sign in, then navigate to the pages. It's unfortunate that there isn't a simple API for this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you will first need to load up the login page, then simulate a form submission (via POST or GET, whatever it is doing), and then store the cookie value(s) that get returned so that you can send them with every request.

Think of it this way -- when you try to pull the page that you want, it is coming from a different client (think browser for simplicity).  Your program is not Internet Explorer, or Firefox, or Chrome...it is it's own new browser.  If you are logged into Windows LIVE in Internet Explorer, then go to  the same page in Firefox, it makes you login again, right?

Well, the only way that the site knows who you are is by the cookies it has put on your machine, and those are browser specific.

So, since you are, in essence, making a new browser, you must store the cookies that get created (that link you with a valid logged in session) and send those in every request.

Comment: @matt-dawdy: When I try to issue a GET request, I keep getting a reply that Windows Live ID requires JavaScript to sign in. How can I make it believe that JavaScript is present? Also, assuming the cookie is returned in the response, how do I access it in code so I can include it in my next GET request?

Comment: Have you ever used Fiddler?  Go get it.  Install it, and start it up.  Then, using IE or Firefox or whatever, log in to Windows Live.  Then look at Fiddler.  You should see your login request, and you will be able to investigate what exactly is being sent, and that will really help you understand what is happening.  Did you read @Ron Harlev's answer? Look at the question he links to and the other link in his answer.  Good stuff there.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that you commented on Ron's post.  It's outdated?  Well, then go back to Fiddler.  You will be able to see exactly what request(s) are sent, and when, and if they are POST or GET.  That will help you figure out how Windows Live is working.